# How to get only one note from relation belongsToMany?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just have a table that has relation belongsToMany, BUT it was a mistake by developer so I can not change this structure SO I need to get only first(). However, when I take only first it return empty array but I need in object

```
    $animals = Cat::query()->with(['types' => function($query) {
       $query->first(); //wrong
    }])
```

So how I can get only first? Because I need to order by this field and I can't because it is array

Comment: are you trying to get multiple cats or just one cat?

Comment: @lagbox all cats and each cat has one type

Comment: write another function to `Cat` class `hasOne` ..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I can not because I have this structure of db for many to many

Comment: did you try with `take()` or `limit()` function ..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Unfortunately, I've already tried and it return empty array

Comment: @Aleks are you here ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221826/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-aleks).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in two ways:

1- using hasOne relation:

```
class Cat {
   public function firstType() {
      
       return $this->hasOne(Type::class, 'type_id', 'id')->latest(); 
}
}
```

2- [using staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit](https://packagist.org/packages/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

after installing it you can write:

```
class Cat extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
 public function firstType() {
      
       return $this->hasMany(Type::class, 'type_id', 'id')->latest()->limit(1); 
}
}

  class Type extends Model
    {
        use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
        //  ...... 
    }
```

the advantage of `HasEagerLimit` trait is that you can limit the result not only to one but any number you want ...

now you can write:

```
 $animals = Cat::query()->with('firstType');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a attribute getter and set up into appends attribute. follow bellow example:

```
class Cat {
   protected $appends = ['type'];

   public function getTypeAttribute() {
       // return the first element from your array of the belongsToMany relationship if it exists
       return  isset($this->types[0])? $this->types[0] : null; 
   }

}
```

> That's important to remember this method will bring just one type. If you want to get the same type everytime, you create a diferente table where the cat table has the type_id column.

obs: Sorry for my english, it's still in working progress.

Comment: How I can add this relation? If I do not have this column in the table.

Comment: @Aleks you can't because the relationship is not a `belongsTo` it is a `belongsToMany` because of the pivot table

Comment: I got it, so i will change a little the example.

Comment: Now you can get the object type from your main belongsToMany relation using the type attribute created.